# How do computers download data, and discern 1's from 0's

Tags: download, data-processing

From my understanding, when a computer downloads something from the internet, a stream of bytes is sent via electrical signals, what I am wondering is how this data is parsed? My first thought was maybe it's based off of some sort of clock, like if your download speed was 1 bps, then it knows that the state of electricity in that 8th of a second represents a bit of 1 or 0, but what if the rate slows to 0.5bps, then every 1/4 second would represent a bit. So with this process:

```
10010110
```

would be seen as:

```
11000011 00111100
```

if this change in rate happened, and as we know, the rate of download changes constantly, so my question is as follows, how does the computer actually interpret the 1's and 0's in the stream? Or is my understanding of a stream incorrect?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it takes BOOKS to answer — it is completely impossible to answer in one StackOverflow answer. The quick summary: this is _roughly_ how things worked about 30-40 years ago, with high and low notes on a telephone line. Now, there's [levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). Electrical impulses are involved at the lowest (physical) level; but download speed fluctuations happen at higher levels, from packet routing, congestion, packet loss, compression variation, and many other factors. If interested, start at the linked page and explore each level.

Comment: @Amadan I understand some of the concepts of the internet such as TCP sending packets with information in the header such as seq, length, ack, and sender info, and that the internet isn't purely 1's and 0's to represent the data, I was mostly just wondering how my own computer would interpret the electrical signals and split them into the full packet.

Comment: I guess you're looking for Physical Medium Attachment (PMA) sublayer of PHY; [this](https://www.ieee802.org/3/cg/public/Nov2017/8023cg_D0p3_T1S_revB.PDF) might be a good read. But other physical protocols might have different ways of handling this; for example IPoAC does not involve electricity at all :P I just wanted to note that varying rate of download has nothing to do with this; the physical layer (AFAIK) functions on a fixed rate.